# Como trazer, em colunas diferentes, valores da mesma coluna de uma outra tabela, com condições diferentes

Tags: mysql

Olá, o que preciso é algo assim:

```
SELECT  users.[UsuarioId]
      , users.[Ativo]
      , users.[TipoFuncaoUsuarioId]
      , users.[ConcessionariaId]
      , users.[DataAdesao]

     (SELECT contato.[Contato] Celular
        FROM [USUARIO_CONTATO] contato, [USUARIO] users
 WHERE users.[UsuarioId] = contato.[UsuarioId]    
 AND   contato.[TipoUsuarioContatoId] = 1) 

    (SELECT contato.[Contato] Residencial
    FROM [USUARIO_CONTATO] contato, [USUARIO] users
 WHERE users.[UsuarioId] = contato.[UsuarioId]    
 AND   contato.[TipoUsuarioContatoId] = 1)
```

O objetivo é trazer os contatos de cada participante, que hoje estão na tabela contato, para essa nova tabela da consulta. O participante tem 4 tipos de contato: celular, residencial, comercial e email. Eles ficam todos na tabela contato, na mesma coluna, e tem ids diferentes.

Obrigada!!

Comment: Veja se ajuda https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2233325&seqNum=4

Answer (score 0):

> O objetivo é trazer os contatos de cada participante, que hoje estão
> na tabela contato, para essa nova tabela da consulta.

Essa consulta pode ser realizada de várias formas, vou demonstrar duas formas, sendo a primeira seguindo o estilo da sua consulta original e a segunda utilizando o comando `CASE`.

### 1ª Forma - Estilo da Consulta Original - Usando Subconsultas

```
SELECT  u.[UsuarioId]
      , u.[Ativo]
      , u.[TipoFuncaoUsuarioId]
      , u.[ConcessionariaId]
      , u.[DataAdesao]
      , (SELECT contato.[Contato] Celular
           FROM [USUARIO_CONTATO] contato
          WHERE contato.[UsuarioId]  = u.[UsuarioId] 
            AND contato.[TipoUsuarioContatoId] = 1)  AS Celular
      , (SELECT contato.[Contato] Celular
           FROM [USUARIO_CONTATO] contato
          WHERE contato.[UsuarioId]  = u.[UsuarioId]   
            AND contato.[TipoUsuarioContatoId] = 2)  AS Residencial
      , (SELECT contato.[Contato] TipoTres
           FROM [USUARIO_CONTATO] contato
          WHERE contato.[UsuarioId]  = u.[UsuarioId]   
            AND contato.[TipoUsuarioContatoId] = 3)  AS TipoTres         
      , (SELECT contato.[Contato] TipoQuatro
           FROM [USUARIO_CONTATO] contato
          WHERE contato.[UsuarioId]  = u.[UsuarioId]   
            AND contato.[TipoUsuarioContatoId] = 4)  AS TipoQuatro
 FROM users u
```

Observe que a Subconsulta referencia `u.[UsuarioId]` da consulta principal, ou seja, para cada usuário serão realizadas 4 subconsultas.

### 2ª Forma: Utilizando o comando `CASE`:

```
 SELECT u.[UsuarioId]
      , u.[Ativo]
      , u.[TipoFuncaoUsuarioId]
      , u.[ConcessionariaId]
      , u.[DataAdesao]
      , CASE WHEN c.TipoUsuarioContatoId = 1 THEN c.Contato END AS Celular
      , CASE WHEN c.TipoUsuarioContatoId = 2 THEN c.Contato END AS Residencial 
      , CASE WHEN c.TipoUsuarioContatoId = 3 THEN c.Contato END AS TipoTres  
      , CASE WHEN c.TipoUsuarioContatoId = 4 THEN c.Contato END AS TipoQuatro  
   FROM users u, USUARIO_CONTATO c
   WHERE u.UsuarioId = c.UsuarioId
```

Nesta solução está sendo realizada uma única consulta nas duas tabelas envolvidas e relacionando-as na cláusula `where`.
Sugiro que utilize essa consulta utilizando o comando `case` por tornar a consulta mais legível, concisa e, acredito eu, performática.
Adeque a consulta à sua realidade substituindo `TipoTres` e `TipoQuatro` mencionados nas consultas conforme a sua realidade.

Comment: Oi Clarck, tudo bem? Primeiro, obrigada pela disponibilidade. Usei o case, mas a consulta duplicou os users, cada um apareceu 4x, sendo que em cada linha ele preencheu um tipo de contato. Eu precisaria que eles viessem na mesma linha da tabela, é possível?

Comment: Tudo bem @Gabi, é possível sim. Você poderia criar uma base pra simulação no http://sqlfiddle.com/? Dessa forma consigo simular a consultar. Após criar a estrutura lá,  você compartilha aqui i link gerado no Fiddle. Pode ser?

Comment: Será necessário incluir uma cláusula `Group by` na consulta para unificar o resultado.